# Can you set a border opacity in CSS?

Tags: css, opacity

Is there a straight forward CSS way to make the border of an element semi-transparent with something like this?

```
border-opacity: 0.7;
```

If not, does anyone have an idea how I could do so without using images?

Comment: Seems that there is no `border-bottom-color-opacity` property. So you are stuck if you cannot touch the color set frontend, and just want to apply opacity for the border bottom color... Also adding opacity to the [currentColor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45075231/1066234) does not work.

Answer (score 794, accepted):

Unfortunately the `opacity` property makes the whole element (including any text) semi-transparent. The best way to make the border semi-transparent is with the rgba color format. For example, this would give a red border with 50% opacity:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
    background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
}
```

For extremely old browsers that don't support rgba (IE8 and older), the solution is to provide two border declarations. The first with a fake opacity, and the second with the actual. If a browser is capable, it will use the second, if not, it will use the first.

```
div {
    border: 1px solid rgb(127, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
    background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
}
```

The first border declaration will be the equivalent color to a 50% opaque red border over a white background (although any graphics under the border will not bleed through).

I've added `background-clip: padding-box;` to the examples above to ensure the border remains transparent even if a solid background color is applied.

Comment: If you're trying to get the content behind your bordered content to shine though (and NOT the background color of the bordered element itself), you'll need to set `background-clip:padding-box;` too.

Comment: hexadecimal with 8 chars works too! eg #000000ff is normal black, and #00000000 is transparent, and those last 2 characters anywhere in between change the opacity

Answer (score 161):

It's easy, use a solid shadow with 0 offset:

```
#foo {
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);       
}
```

Also, if you set a border-radius to the element, it gives you pretty rounded borders

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KDs3v/1/)

[image]

Comment: This will always work. Thanks for the snippet :) For everyone, who only wants to have a border to one or more sites you have to change the two first paramters like that box-shadow: -1px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) to achieve e.g. border-top

Comment: This one should be used with caution! `box-shadow` has no size and can break your layout, making you margins uneven! http://jsfiddle.net/bj81hew7/2/

Comment: I mean, this is cool, but the way you made the box-shadow translucent works the exact same way for actual borders, so I don't know how this **answers** the question. it's just a neat addition

Answer (score 19):

As others have mentioned, CSS3 supports the `rgba(...)` syntax to specify a border color with an opacity (alpha) value.

[Here's a quick JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pqH4r/) if you'd like to check it.

- It works in Safari and Chrome (probably works in all webkit browsers).
- It works in Firefox
- I doubt that it works at all in IE, but I suspect that there is some filter or behavior that will make it work.

There's also [CSS RGBA border / background alpha double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626039/css-rgba-border-background-alpha-double), which suggests some other issues—namely, that the border renders on-top-of any background color (or background image) that you've specified; thus limiting the usefulness of border alpha in many cases.

Comment: The border issue can be cured with `background-clip: padding-box;` (and until that is supported, you can use the -webkit and -moz vendor extensions).

Comment: I've added this answer to the question you've linked to.

Answer (score 9):

If you check your CSS coding with W3C validator, you will see if your CSS code is acceptable, even if it worked in the major browsers.

Creating a transparent border via CSS, as written above,

```
border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
```

is not accepted by W3C standards, not even for CSS3. I used the direct input validator with the following CSS code,

```
.test { border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5); }
```

The results were,

> Value Error : border Too many values or values are not recognized :
>   1px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5 )

Unfortunate that the alpha value (the letter "a" at the end of "rgb") is not accepted by W3C as part of the border color values as yet. I do wonder why it is not standardized, since it works in all browsers. The only hitch is whether you want to stick to W3C standards or step aside from it to create something in CSS.

To use [W3C online CSS validator / Direct Input](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input).

Always a good idea to use a validator to check your work, it really helps finding small or even large errors in coding when your going cross-eyed after hours of coding work.

Comment: Wrong, this is perfectly acceptable by W3C standards, and is a bug in the validator. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317057/how-to-validate-css3-hsla-color-values/9317224#9317224). It's a good idea to use the validator, yes, but don't trust it for everything.

Answer (score 5):

*Not as far as i know there isn't what i do normally in this kind of circumstances is create a block beneath with a bigger size((bordersize*2)+originalsize) and make it transparent using

```
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity:0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
```

here is an example

```
#main{
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.border{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#F00;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.content{
    margin:15px;/*size of border*/
    background-color:black;
}
<div id="main">
    <div class="border">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        testing
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

This answer is outdated, since after all this question is more than 8 years old. Today all up to date browsers support rgba, box shadows and so on. But this is a decent example how it was 8+ years ago.

Comment: Yeah that is what i ended up doing actually, it just sucks fudging with the positioning of the elements.

Comment: it *can* be done - but not with broad cross-browser support.  However, chances are good that any browser that supports css opacity on background color would also support `rgba(...)` in border colors.  [you can try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/pqH4r/).

Comment: @Lee, IE supports the "filter" opacity, but not any form of rgba (until IE9).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate solution that *may* work in *some* cases: change the `border-style` to `dotted`.

Having alternating groups of pixels between the foreground color and the background color isn't the same as a continuous line of partially transparent pixels. On the other hand, this requires significantly less CSS and it is much more compatible across every browser without any browser-specific directives.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers deal with the technical aspect of the border-opacity issue, while I'd like to present a hack(pure CSS and HTML only). Basically create a container div, having a border div and then the content div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="border-box"></div>
  <div class="content-box"></div>
</div>
```

And then the CSS:(set content border to none, take care of positioning such that border thickness is accounted for)

```
.container {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  position: relative;
}
.border-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.content-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: green;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One may also consider other border styles (`dashed`, `dotted`) to make the border partly fully transparent:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/c1rvp3ga

```css
body {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/pr86mh.jpg');
}

#foo {
  border: 5px dashed #b00;
  background: #ddd;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p id=foo>some content</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside the box a bit here: if you are working with [SVG basic shapes](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/shapes.html#Introduction), you can use a combination of `stroke`, `stroke-width` ([browser support > 97%](https://caniuse.com/?search=stroke-width)), and `stroke-opacity` ([browser support > 99%](https://caniuse.com/?search=stroke-opacity)) to do essentially the same thing the OP is asking.

For example, this declaration:

```
circle {
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 5px;
    stroke-opacity: 0.4
}
```

will add a translucent blue halo around the perimeter of a `<circle>` with `#000` fill.

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CSSBurner/7n4rpoub/) provides a demo for several SVG basic shapes. The fiddle uses a red `fill` and blue `stroke` to highlight a major difference here between `stroke` and `border` - half the `stroke-width` is inside the perimeter of the basic shape.

This gives a "double border" appearance (from outside towards the center for each basic shape: blue->(blue + red = purple)->red) that would be impossible to achieve with CSS `border` alone (but `border` + `outline` *could* - see the above JSFiddle for an example using a `<div>`), and difficult to achieve (in the case of radial basic shapes) with a `radial-gradient()`.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<h2>Snippet for making borders transparent</h2>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.
    Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</b>. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim
    lacinia nunc. <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor.
    <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</i>. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod
    in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis
    turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. <b>Nam nec ante</b>. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. <i>Sed convallis tristique sem</i>.
    Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. <b>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos</b>. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum
    ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc,
    viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. <b>Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit</b>. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. </p>
</div>
<div id="transparentBorder">
  This &lt;div&gt; has transparent borders.
</div>
```

And here comes our magical CSS..

```
* {
  padding: 10pt;
  font: 13px/1.5 Helvetica Neue, Arial, Helvetica, 'Liberation Sans', FreeSans, sans-serif;
}

b {
  font-weight: bold;
}

i {
  font-style: oblique;
}

H2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

div[id='transparentBorder'] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  background: Black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 10pt solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-background-clip: border;
  /* Firefox 3.6 */
  -webkit-background-clip: border;
  /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
  background-clip: border-box;
  /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  /* Firefox 3.6 */
  -webkit-background-clip: padding;
  /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Check out the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darkdemon666/D529s/24/) here.

Answer (score -2):

Since this answer is top of Google results, decided to post an updated (2021) answer for the rookies like me.

You can set a border opacity buy using an rgba color.

```
border:2px solid rgba(232, 69, 69,.5); /* notice the .5 */
```

See example fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/joshdane/74pybasm/33/

You can use it, and enjoy it.

There is some discussion that [older browsers don't support rgba](https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/), but most people are [not using older browsers anymore](https://www.w3counter.com/trends). If you are just learning, don't worry about supporting older browsers.

[image]

Comment: The accepted answer at the top of the page already gives the solution of using `rgba()`. Answers should focus on *novel* solutions to the question, not repeat existing answers.

Comment: @TylerH that answer is from 2010 and makes it seem like it is not well supported. It is very well supported now. What would be the best way to help new programmers like myself recognize that?

Comment: If the only issue is that it "makes it seem like it's not well supported", then just... comment or edit it to make it clear that it is. Don't just repeat the answer in another one. Anyway, I don't see how "for old browsers like IE8 and older" indicates in *any* way that it is not well supported.