# "non-opacity" border for "opacity" element

Tags: html, css

Given this html

```
    <div id="my_div">   
    </div>
```

css

```
         #my_div {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px; 
            background-color: #0f0;
            opacity: 0.4; 
            border: 3px solid #ff0000;
         }
```

I want that own div tag will `opacity`, but dont need border also.

css can make "non-opacity" border for "opacity" element?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what your asking (language barrier) but the border's opacity will be the same as the element's opacity.

Comment: No, but you could make a div for the border around the transparent div.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Border Opacity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062001/css3-border-opacity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a `non-opacity` attribute but what you can do is set the background colour of that div with RGBA. This allows you to specify an opacity essentially, but just for the background (so it won't affect the border)

```
background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
```

This will achieve what you want, a red border with that transparent looking background. [Demo HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/B3aHG/). This won't however, make inner content, such as images or text transparent. Though you can set the opacity on those elements freely without worrying about the border of the parent.

You can find a good article that details the difference between opacity and RGBA [here](http://deepubalan.com/blog/2010/03/29/rgba-vs-opacity-the-difference-explained/) and [here](http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/)

It should be noted that, as expected, [IE8 and below do not support RGBA](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors), though it can be "hacked" with [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

Comment: Actually alien was first to answer but you got a cookie ;)

Comment: Yes, alien was faster, but Andy give slightly more  completely answer... and I via coin decided and accept Andy's answer =)

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 5):

Use CSS3 `rgba`, It's CSS so cross-browser will be an issue here, but for IE you can use CSS3 [Pie](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/)

```
#my_div {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px; 
     background-color: rgba(R, G, B, A);
     border: 3px solid #ff0000;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SgQEf/)

Moreover using `rgba()` for opaque container won't make your text opaque as using `opacity: .7` used to do...

Comment: @F4r-20 It's a good property, not supported by IE as usual but you can use PIE

Comment: @F4r-20 yup, you got it right, it's alpha, also there's a new 1, `HSLa`

Answer (score 2):

See the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062032/1068266

It states that you can use the RGBA format for the border color, and by setting the "A" value you can set the opacity of the border. As stated in the comments however, the opacity CSS property sets the opacity for the entire object, including the border.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, when you apply opacity to an element, it is also applied to any margin, padding or border applied to the element.

The best solution would be to use rgba (as previously posted) and have a 1x1 opaque png as a fallback for legacy browsers (if you support them) and use it as the background image for the element.

One disadvantage to using the opacity property is if your #my_div contains any content (text or images), the content itself will also have that opacity and would likely result in unwanted styling.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I'm afraid the only way will be to wrap your div with another div which will have border:</s>
One of the ways would be like this (keeping opacity of all inner elements):

```
<div class="border">
    <div id="my_div">   
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.border{
   border: 3px solid #ff0000;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px; 
}
#my_div {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px; 
   background-color: #0f0;
   opacity: 0.4;                 
}
```

Or like others told: rgba for background color, but all inner content will stay non transparent in that case