# How to make a transparent border using CSS?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to do something like this for a client who has a blog.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h31s.png]

She wanted a semi transparent border. I know that's possible with making it just a background. But I can't seem to find the logic/code behind this kind of css technique for banners. Does anybody know how to do this? It would be a lot of help because that's the look my client's wanting to achieve for his blog....

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062001/css3-border-opacity

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6qJcc/1/

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Well if you want fully transparent than you can use

```
border: 5px solid transparent;
```

If you mean opaque/transparent, than you can use

```
border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
```

Here, `a` means alpha, which you can scale, 0-1.

Also some might suggest you to use `opacity` which does the same job as well, the only difference is it will result in child elements getting opaque too, yes, there are some work arounds but `rgba` seems better than using `opacity`.

For older browsers, always declare the background color using `#`(hex) just as a fall back, so that if old browsers doesn't recognize the `rgba`, they will apply the `hex` color to your element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbCrr/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbCrr/2/) (With a background image for nested div)

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbCrr/6/) (With an `img` tag instead of a `background-image`)

```
body {
    background: url(http://www.desktopas.com/files/2013/06/Images-1920x1200.jpg);   
}

div.wrap {
    border: 5px solid #fff; /* Fall back, not used in fiddle */
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

div.inner {
    background: #fff; /* Fall back, not used in fiddle */
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    height: 380px;
    width: 380px;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    margin: auto; /* Horizontal Center */
    margin-top: 10px; /* Vertical Center ... Yea I know, that's 
                         manually calculated*/
}
```

> Note (For Demo 3): Image will be scaled according to the height and
>   width provided so make sure it doesn't break the scaling ratio.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use `border-style: double` with `background-clip: padding-box`, without the use of any extra (pseudo-)elements. It's probably the most compact solution, but not as flexible as the others.

[For example](http://jsfiddle.net/m7hhr/):

```
<div class="circle">Some text goes here...</div>

.circle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    border: double 15px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

[image: Result]

If you look closely you can see that the edge between the border and the background is not perfect. This seems to be an issue in current browsers. But it's not that noticeable when the border is small.

Comment: This allows it to work with no additional markup and [has pretty good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts). `background-color` plus `border:double` doesn't work for transparency between the borders without the `background-clip` style.

Answer (score 11):

Using the `:before` pseudo-element,
CSS3's `border-radius`,
and some **transparency** is quite easy:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/enenob/1/edit)**

[image]

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.circle, .circle:before{
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:150px;  
}
.circle{  
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  z-index:0;
  margin:11%;
  padding:40px;
  background: hsla(0, 100%, 100%, 0.6);   
}
.circle:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  z-index:-1;  
  width:200px;
  height:200px;

  padding:44px;
  border: 6px solid hsla(0, 100%, 100%, 0.6);
  /* 4px more padding + 6px border = 10 so... */  
  top:-10px;
  left:-10px; 
}
```

The `:before` attaches to our `.circle` another element which you only need to make (ok, block, absolute, etc...) transparent and play with the **border opacity**.

Answer (score 2):

use `rgba` (rgb with `alpha  transparency`):

```
border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); // 0.5 means 50% of opacity
```

The `alpha transparency` variate between 0 (0% opacity = 100% transparent) and 1 (100 opacity = 0% transparent)

Comment: You cant avoid the use of "background-clip: padding-box;" if you want a distinct border. Without this css property, the background color will fill all the div, your border will be stacked with the background color.