# Transparent border over image

Tags: css

I am trying to create a transparent border for my image and place it over the image using CSS.

For example please see the image below:

[image]

To achieve this I tried the following code but I am facing the following problems:

1. The border is not over the image; its around the image and not allowing the image to fit 100% inside the parent div
2. To Make the border transparent I used "opacity" but its making the image transparent too which I don't want.

You can check the code live here: http://jsfiddle.net/6GK45/

I could create a div and made the border color transparent and then place it over the image but the problem is the width of my image is fixed (277px) but the height is not. So this will not work for me.

Could you please tell me how to create the transparent image border and place it over the image just like in the image above.?

HTML:

```
<div class="box" >  
   <img class="lightbox" src="myimage.jpg" />
   This is text
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width:277px; 
    background:#FCFBDF;    
}

.lightbox {
    border: 5px solid red;
    z-index:999; 
    opacity:0.3; 
}

img {
    width:277px;
}
```

Comment: @andi essentially the same thing, you get the point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a transparent border using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751093/how-to-make-a-transparent-border-using-css)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How's this - it uses :after to create a pseudo-element which places the border on top of the image, not outside it.  http://jsfiddle.net/6GK45/8/

```
.imgWrap:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
    opacity:0.5;
    border:5px solid red;
}
```

**UPDATE:** If it's important to preserve the ability to right-click on the image, you can do it like this with an additional wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/6GK45/24/

Comment: Good one. It was obviously needed to make a sibling to the image, but it didn't occur to me to use :after !

Comment: Just need an `rgba` color instead of `red` and this works nicely.

Comment: an rgba color is functionally the same as using opacity here, no?

Comment: Actually, I did not notice the `opacity` property, and you are absolutely right in this particular application.  Either way is good.  `opacity` may be better supported on older browsers compared to `rgba`, that may be the reason to pick one over the other.

Comment: Downside of this solution is that image context menu (Save image/Copy image/Open in new tab) no longer accessible.

Comment: To preserve the ability to right-click on the image, you don't need additional wrapper; `pointer-events: none;` is sufficient. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @JoeyHoer - can you provide a fiddle to demonstrate that?

Answer (score 7):

For anyone still googling for this: It is possible to achieve this effect with CSS only by using the `outline` property:

```css
img {
  outline: 15px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .75);
  outline-offset: -15px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2012/12/04/article-2242647-0F79C42300000578-201_634x429.jpg" width=250 />
```

Answer (score 4):

As Donovan said, rgba for the border-color – but the border on an element containing the image, and then the image “pulled” outwards under the border using a negative margin and z-index – like this, http://jsfiddle.net/6GK45/7/

```
<div class="box" >  
    <span class="lightbox"><img …></span>
…
</div>

.lightbox{
   display:block;
   width:267px;
   border:5px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}
.lightbox img{
    display:block;
    width:277px;
    margin:-5px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a border with opacity, you can use `RGBA` code. The 'A' signify `alpha`, so you can modify opacity.

```
border: 5px solid rgba(255,0,0, 0.3) ;
```

You can use `z-index` to put your box with border above your image if you put image and box in position absolute, relative.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/6GK45/21/

What you need to do is set the image as the background of the parent div and then adjust the width/height of the child div to hug the image accordingly.

```
//make js fiddle work
```