# How to mask semi circles inside a rectangle and mask through css?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image and a rectangle made in css above it. What i need is, two semi circles should mask through this rectangle and background image should be seen through this rectangle as shown in the image.

[image]

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17751125/1542290)?

Comment: Also, close voting your question as you haven't tried, nor you shared your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="rect"></div>
    <div id="a">    
    </div>  
    <div id="b">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:312px;
    height:313px;
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZVTb.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#a{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    height:120px;
    top:100px;
    border-top-left-radius:60px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:60px;
    width:60px;
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZVTb.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;}
#b{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    height:120px;
    top:100px;
    border-top-right-radius:60px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:60px;
    width:60px;
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZVTb.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
} 
#rect{
    width:100%;
    height:56%;
    position:absolute;
    top:65px;
    background:rgba(120,0,23,.8);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DDnRs/29/)

**Output**:

[image]

Change the color and image as you want.!!!!

Also check this  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17751125/1542290

Comment: i need a transparent rectangle and semicircles are masked through them. Background is seen clearly through these circles.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by controlling the opacity of the rectangle.
Something like this : (0% opacity = 100% transparent) and 1 (100 opacity = 0% transparent)

Answer (score 0):

The following is the css code

```
.bckgrnd{
background:url('image.jpg');
width:1000px;
height:500px;
}


.rect{
position:relative;
width:700px;
height:200px;
background:pink;
opacity:0.5;
top:100px;
left:150px;
}

.semi{
height:100px;
width:50px;
background:url(image.jpg);
background-attachment:fixed;
position:absolute;
top:40px;
}

.right{
left:0;
border-radius :0 50px 50px 0;
}

.left{
right:0;
border-radius :50px 0 0 50px;
}
```

and the html mark up as follows

```
<div class="bckgrnd">
    <div class="rect">
        <div class="semi right"></div>
        <div class="semi left"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```