# How can I set the opacity of border

Tags: css

How to set the opacity of the border?

I want it to be transparent so that objects behind the border will be seen.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/4062032/1305911

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

`border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); // 50% opacity`

The last value varies from 0 to 1. Where 0 is completely transparent and 1 is Opaque.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should do the trick:

```
border: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

More info: http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rgba` format in modern browsers.

`border: 2px solid rgba(0, 51, 255, 0.5)`

You can use it in all modern browsers. Here's a [list](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba)

Answer (score 0):

You **Can't** Do it. because the "`objects behind the borders`" is the object itself.

check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mRT3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Choose any CSS colour function with an alpha channel:

`rgba(RR, GG, BB, ALPHA)` or `hsla(HUE, SAT, LUM, ALPHA)`

The alpha value is between `0` and `1`.

You *may* also want to have a look into [`background-clip`](http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/) property for defining the position of the background in relation to the box-model of the element.