# How do you change a table border opacity

Tags: php, html, css

I have a webpage with a gradient background image.  On this page is a table.  I have set the borders to a 5px width and solid.  I would like to make these borders opacity to 0% so users see the gradient background instead.  Is this possible.  This is the table I have so far.

```
<div style="margin: 0pt auto; width: 980px;background-color:white;">
<div style="500px;overflow:hidden">
    <table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="border-bottom:5px solid rgba(255,0,0,.5);"><font color="red">Name</font></th>
        <th style="border-bottom:5px solid rgba(255,0,0,.5);"><font color="green">Event</font>        </th>
        <th style="border-bottom:5px solid rgba(255,0,0,.5);"><font color="blue">Description</font></th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid red;"><?         echo $Row['name']; ?></td>
        <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid green;"><? echo $Row['description']; ?></td>
        <td style="width:150px;border-bottom:1px solid blue;"><? echo $Row['detail']; ?></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
</div>
```

I changed the color to rgba(255,0,0,.05) as previously suggested but it shows the white background set for the division outside the table.  I want to show the true page background for the borders of the table which is a multicolored gradient.

This has been tagged as a duplicate but I was not told where the original question is.  Using the rgb or rgba only changes the opacity to the background of the table cells.  I want to show the page background which is behind the table which is a colored gradient.  If this is a duplicated question please show me where the answer has been given.  Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062001/css3-border-opacity ?

Comment: Do you mean opacity to 0% (invisible) rather than opacity to 100% (visible)?

Answer (score 2):

Use rgba: `border-bottom:5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);`

The lower the 4th nr the more transparent it will look. My example shows red.

Answer (score 1):

find the RGB breakdown for the color you want (google it) and use

```
5px solid rgba(255,0,0,.5)
```

`.5` is the alpha which is the transparency