# currentColor with opacity

Tags: html, css

Is there a method in which I can change the opacity of a border which is being set to inherit it's color from `currentColor`? i.e. inherit `currentColor` in `#inner2` and set it's opacity to `0.25`.

Searching for a pure `css` solution please.

For example, something which resembles the following:

```css
#outer{
  color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

.inner{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
}

#inner2{
  /* This is where I want to inherit current color */
  /* ... but still set it to 0.25 opacity */
  border-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.25);
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner1' class='inner'></div>
  <div id='inner2' class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: impossible... you can use tricks like `before/after` which inherit the color and then you can set `opacity` on those.

Comment: If you want to use like that , sass scss will the best for you !!!

Comment: Related - [How do I apply opacity to a CSS color variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40010597/104380)

Comment: i thought of a stupid thing, how about making the outer opacity 0.25 so the one inheriting it receives it clean no need to change, then for the outer you layer 4 of it lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now achieve this in a more direct way, at least in modern browsers, using the [`color-mix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix) function.

Example:

```css
#outer {
  color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}

.inner {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
}

#inner2 {
  border-color: color-mix(in srgb, currentColor 25%, transparent);
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner1' class='inner'></div>
  <div id='inner2' class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

You can choose a colour space (I chose SRGB for you here), and the proportion for the mixture. If you leave out the proportion, it defaults to 50%.

Note, however, that if the current colour is already partially transparent, this will make it *more* transparent; this does not *replace* the alpha channel. For that we need to wait for [relative colors](https://caniuse.com/css-relative-colors) ([another part of CSS Color Level 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-5/#relative-color-function)).

Comment: Yes to `color-mix`!. I can now have hundreds of elements on the page with a translucent layer on them without blowing up my RAM usage. `opacity` creates a new `stacking context` (layer) per element which isn't always the best practice.

Answer (score 20):

## [color-mix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix)

*[caniuse support table](https://caniuse.com/?search=color-mix)*

`color-mix` can be used to mix `currentColor` with other colors (like `transparent`):

```css
html {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 700 6em Arial;
  
  /* actual fun: */
  color: Salmon;
  background: color-mix(in srgb, currentColor 20%, transparent);
  border: 20px solid color-mix(in srgb, currentColor 50%, transparent);
}
```

```html
AWESOME
```

---

#### Previous answer:

You are confusing `currentColor` value with `inherit` which is the *default*. you don't use `currentColor` for `border` properties because that it the default value for the `border`.

`#inner1` and `#inner2` both inherit from the closest parent which has a color set to it (red) and the border is using that color by default.

##### Below solution will work 100% of the time, regardless of the color's source
 (inline `style` attribute, external CSS or distant ancestor inheritance):

```css
#outer{ color:red; }
#inner1, #inner2{ 
    padding: 2em; 
    margin-top: 1em;  
}
#inner1{ border:5px solid; } 

#inner2{ position:relative; }

#inner2::before{  
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  border:5px solid;
  opacity:.5;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner1'>inner 1</div>
  <div id='inner2'>inner 2</div>
</div>
```

Also, see my [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71098929/104380) which uses cutting-edge syntax.

Comment: hmmm ok yeah, interesting... this seems like a feasible solution. Is `#inner2` smaller than `#inner1` in the example - not sure why though>?

Comment: yes it acts different since the border is not a real part of the div, but is *over* it, so it does not take any space. you can solve this by using `box-shadow` on both, instead of `border`, or just compensate using different `padding` on the second `div`

Comment: @Zze - give `#inner1` - `box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px inset;` instead of border :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use css-variables to achieve similar behaviour:

```css
#outer{
  --border-r: 255;
  --border-g: 0;
  --border-b: 0;
  color: rgba(var(--border-r),var(--border-g),var(--border-b),1);
}

.inner{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

#inner2{
  color: rgba(var(--border-r),var(--border-g),var(--border-b),0.25);
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner1' class='inner'></div>
  <div id='inner2' class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need to write `currentColor` in the border, it's meaningless.

Comment: Thx, I forgot to remove it =)

Comment: while this works, this solution is not *flexible*, since the colors might come from an inline `style` attribute or external CSS file, or if the color is coming from an unknown distant ancestor (so you cannot exactly know where to set up the variables)

Comment: I was inspired by this, I *do* think this does work, just needed some tweaks. Check out this demo: https://codepen.io/nicetransition/pen/bGWOVMN

Comment: @vsync `currentColor` is the color of the text of that same element, it's not meaningless. If you want the border to be the same as `color:` property than use currentColor

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
:root {
  --color-r: 0;
  --color-g: 0;
  --color-b: 0;
  --color-a: 1;
}

[class*=-color] {
  color: rgba(var(--color-r), var(--color-g), var(--color-b), var(--color-a));
}

[class*=-background] {
  --background-r: var(--color-r);
  --background-g: var(--color-g);
  --background-b: var(--color-b);
  --background-color-a: var(--color-a);
  background-color: rgba(var(--color-r), var(--color-g), var(--color-b), var(--color-a));
}

[class*=dark] {
  --color-r: 0;
  --color-g: 0;
  --color-b: 0;
}

[class*=light] {
  --color-r: 255;
  --color-g: 255;
  --color-b: 255;
}

[class*=primary] {
  --color-r: 200;
  --color-g: 2;
  --color-b: 33;
}

[class*=secondary] {
  --color-r: 102;
  --color-g: 102;
  --color-b: 102;
}

[class*="--alpha-0"], [class*="--alpha-00"] {
  --color-a: 0;
}

[class*="--alpha-10"] {
  --color-a: .1;
}

[class*="--alpha-20"] {
  --color-a: .2;
}

[class*="--alpha-30"] {
  --color-a: .3;
}

[class*="--alpha-40"] {
  --color-a: .4;
}

[class*="--alpha-50"] {
  --color-a: .5;
}

[class*="--alpha-60"] {
  --color-a: .6;
}

[class*="--alpha-70"] {
  --color-a: .7;
}

[class*="--alpha-80"] {
  --color-a: .8;
}

[class*="--alpha-90"] {
  --color-a: .9;
}

[class*="--alpha-100"] {
  --color-a: 1;
}
```