# How to Add Opacity to CSS Variable Color?

Tags: css

I have created a CSS variable

```
--border-color: #b8b8c4;
```

Trying to add opacity to the border

```
border-color: 1px solid rgba(var(--border-color), 0.5);
```

I created a CSS variable and tried to add opacity to it as shown in one StackOverflow solution. But it is not working.

Some solution, please.

Comment: you're using hex color but putting it inside rgba...try setting the color in rgba format first

Comment: RGB for your hex code is `rgb(184,184,196)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you set a border opacity in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062001/can-you-set-a-border-opacity-in-css)

Answer (score 2):

```css
--border-color: 184, 184, 196;
border-color: 1px solid rgba(var(--border-color), 0.5);
```